# Unknown helper createSuper Error in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i just updated my create-next-app from 9.1 to 9.3(the latest version) and got this error, couldn't figure out how to solve it. Help pls!

and now again, i installed npm with my older package.json file and still getting this error... what is it? , if anyone know pls share it.

```
[ error ] ./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js
ReferenceError: D:\code\project\webapp\node_modules\next\dist\client\index.js: Unknown helper createSuper
[ wait ]  compiling ...
[ error ] ./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js
ReferenceError: D:\code\project\webapp\node_modules\next\dist\client\index.js: Unknown helper createSuper
[ event ] build page: /next/dist/pages/_error
[ wait ]  compiling ...
[ error ] ./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js
ReferenceError: D:\code\project\webapp\node_modules\next\dist\client\index.js: Unknown helper createSuper
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\code\project\webapp\.next\build-manifest.json'
Require stack:
- D:\code\project\webapp\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\load-components.js
- D:\code\project\webapp\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\api-utils.js
- D:\code\project\webapp\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js
- D:\code\project\webapp\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js
- D:\code\project\webapp\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js
- D:\code\project\webapp\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js
- D:\code\project\webapp\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:954:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:847:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:69:18)
    at Object.loadComponents (D:\code\project\webapp\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\load-components.js:29:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue introduced by babel-loader@8.1.0

See https://github.com/zeit/next.js/discussions/11233#discussioncomment-1739

Answer (score 0):

Either upgrade Babel to 7.9.0 or pin babel-loader to 8.0.6.

Note - If you are on Heroku: when upgrading, make sure the node-modules contains the correct babel package.  In heroku this is possible with `heroku ps:exec` and looking in the node-modules/ directory.

Many other packages may be relying on an older version of Babel and they will need to be upgraded as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### My fix for

### error - ./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/amp-dev.js

[image]

- It seems that your global `./node_modules/next/dist/client` package is missing or misconfigured.

### My Solution was to

1. Delete this folder or even the entire `next` folder from your root `./node_modules/next`
2. Run `npm i` to install new `node_modules` packages

This resolved my errors.